# Excel Macros recording

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How do I using a button (Add), copy a few cells from sheet 1 and paste into another sheet using macros? Everytime the Add button is clicked, a new row will be added. I have been trying and it keeps pasting onto the same row and not adding a new row. How do I resolve this problem? Any assistance on how should I record the macro?

Comment: Have you tried recording using the insert copied cells option instead of just pasting in the second sheet?

Comment: Could you post the recorded macro?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are recording your macro by selecting the top of your range, then pressing **end** and then **down arrow**, then **down arrow** once more to get the first blank cell? And then of course, pasting.

If so, it's probably making a macro something like this:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The problem is obviously that pressing the **down arrow** is just making a new absolute selection (in my example's case, A6), rather than moving down one more cell.
Simply edit the macro, changing that line to make a relative step, rather than an absolute selection. So now it will look something like this:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1,0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```